# URL Hacking not null validation rule in custom button

Tags: custom-button, validation-rule, urlhacking

I have created 'Create Oppty' button on custom object **License**. Which is pre-populating some values on Oppty from License. I want to add one validation rule in this button like : `Quantity != Blank.Quantity` is Number type field.

Can we achieve this using URL hacking?

Comment: No, URL hack will allow you only to prepopulate fields, but not do a validation on save. Use Validation Rules for that

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE! As written, we don't have enough information to help you. Please read more about [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), then [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/225898/edit) your question to include additional details. Details like any error messages, framework error messages, the button code that you have buit till now, etc would be useful, as well as the code you've written so far.